# xpath returns more than one result, how to handle in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have started selenium using python. I am able to change the message text using find_element_by_id. I want to do the same with find_element_by_xpath which is not successful as the xpath has two instances. want to try this out to learn about xpath.

I want to do web scraping of a page using python in  which I need clarity on using Xpath mainly needed for going to next page.

```
#This code works:
import time
import requests
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html"
driver.get(url)
eleUserMessage = driver.find_element_by_id("user-message")
eleUserMessage.clear()
eleUserMessage.send_keys("Testing Python")
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
#This works fine. I wish to do the same with xpath. 
#I inspect the the Input box in chrome, copy the xpath '//*[@id="user-message"]' which seems to refer to the other box as well.
# I wish to use xpath method to write text in this box as follows which does not work.

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html"
driver.get(url)
eleUserMessage = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-message"]')
eleUserMessage.clear()
eleUserMessage.send_keys("Test Python")
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `find_elements_by_xpath` which will return a list and you can index it? (emphasis on element**s** instead of element). If there are 2 instances, your list will have 2 items in the order they appear on the page.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment you would use a list like this:

```
eleUserMessage_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-message"]')
my_desired_element = eleUserMessage_list[0] # or maybe [1]
my_desired_element.clear()
my_desired_element.send_keys("Test Python")
time.sleep(2)
```

The only real difference between `find_elements_by_xpath` and `find_element_by_xpath` is the first option returns a list that needs to be indexed. Once it's indexed, it works the same as if you had run the second option!

Comment: Thanks it worked.  Timely help when one is struggling to start.

Comment: @Ravi Glad to hear it worked! It's common practice on StackOverflow to click the check mark next to the post that solves your problem, so future viewers with the same problem will know what solution worked! When you get to 15 rep you can up-vote helpful questions and answers too! Welcome to SO.